# Jquery .offset to scroll to content after click, now it won't stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My page is set up of a header image with a jquery accordion below with a bunch of items. In the header image I have click maps set up so that the user can click on a part of the header image and then view the content below. As of now, it works. However it won't stop working... I set up an anchor id within the accordion header like below...

```
<div class="accordionClass">
   <h3><a id="accordionID"></a>Accordion Title</h3>
   <div>
      <p>accordion Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

the jQuery that makes it all happen looks a bit like this...

```
$( "#mapAreaID" ).click(function() { 
        $( ".accordionClass" ).accordion({ active: 1, collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", activate: function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#accordionID").offset().top},
            'slow');
        }, });
     };
);
```

This seems to be working just fine for the functionality that I'm looking for, but it is one of those problems where you fix 1 issue, but cause another...

When you click the map up in the header, the appropriate accordion expands with the active index #, then after it opens the screen scrolls down to the anchor placed into the h3 tag. great! but now, if you scroll up/down and click another accordion item from the list. The page now keeps scrolling up/down to the offset anchor selected at the beginning. It keeps doing this over and over again.

What I would like it to do is animate to that spot, and just finish. I don't' want to remove the button up top just in case the user wants to 'jump' to that content again, but remove/stop that animation from reoccurring. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT - Just noticed that if I create a seperate accordion with a different class name, it doesn't jump to the anchor. So this issue only happens when I click elements inside the same class of "accordionClass". I think I'm missing something small...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.

It may not be the cleanest solution, but I managed to find out what was causing it & it works.

the issue was that I was setting up an animation after the .accordionClass was "activated". By doing that It set the specific offset every time any item in that class was "activated". So...

What I did was keeping the animation code as is and incorporated a function that fires after the animation completes that "resets" the activate status of the accordion.

Here's the revision of the code...

```
$( "#mapAreaID" ).click(function() { 
        $( ".accordionClass" ).accordion({ active: 1, collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", activate: function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#accordionID").offset().top},
            'slow', killActivate);
        }, });
     };
);

function killActivate (){
        $('html,body').finish();
        $( ".accordionClass" ).accordion({
            activate: 
                function() {
                    console.log("do nothing")
                }
        });
    }
```